# Automate CSV file cleaning with AWS lambda using a trigger

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda function which will clean automatically csv files from an S3 bucket.
The S3 bucket receives files every 5mn, and I have therefore created a trigger for the Lambda function.
To clean the csv files I will use pandas library to create a dataframe. I have already installed a pandas layer. When creating a dataframe, there is an error message.
This is my code:

```
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


#call s3 bucket
client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #define bucket_name and object _name
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    #create a df from the object
    df = pd.read_csv(object_name)
```

This is the error message:

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'object_name'
```

On Cloudwatch it additionally says:

```
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
```

Has anyone experienced the same issues? Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: `read_csv("object_name")` - I hope you noticed that `"object_name"` is a string here and not the actual variable declared 2 lines above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I have changed it to read_csv(object_name), and I get the following error message:    "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test%2Fkey'",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the s3 client to download the file from s3 before using pandas.  Something like:

```
response = client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)
df = pd.read_csv(response["Body"])
```

You'll have to make sure lambda has the right permissions to access the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

df = pd.read_csv("object_name")

to this:

df = pd.read_csv(object_name)

Comment: thank you ! just updated it, however still an error message..

Comment: I changed it in the post, thanks for your insight!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### Cause of error

`object_name` is just a relative path(key) of the s3 object with respect to bucket and it has no significance without the `bucket_name` hence when you are trying to read the csv file you are getting `FileNotFoundError`

##### Solution for the error

In order to properly refer the s3 object you have to construct the fully qualified s3 path from `bucket_name` and `object_name`. Also notice that the object key has some quoted characters so before constructing the fully qualified path you have to unquote them.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #define bucket_name and object _name
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    #create a df from the object
    filepath = f's3://{bucket_name}/{unquote_plus(object_name)}'
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```